# Dynamically change <li> width to fully fit in <ul>

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to display elements for a Media Library with this structure:

```css
.mail-attach-list {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.mail-attach-list>li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 190px;
}
.thumbnail {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
    background-color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.mail-attach-list>li .mail-file-img, .mail-attach-list>li .mail-file-icon {
    height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
}
.thumbnail .caption {
    padding: 9px;
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mail-attach-list list-ov">
    <li class="item">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <div class="mail-file-icon">
                <i class="pli-file-excel"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="caption">
                <p class="text-primary mar-no text-overflow">Icon Example</p>
                <small class="text-muted text-overflow">
                    Added: <time data-toggle="timeago">4 days ago</time>
                </small>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <div class="mail-file-img">
                <img class="image-responsive" src="/uploads/2017/09/bg-img-7-400x300.jpg" alt="image">
            </div>
            <div class="caption">
                <p class="text-primary mar-no text-overflow">Image example</p>
                <small class="text-muted text-overflow">
                    Added: <time data-toggle="timeago">4 days ago</time>
                </small>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

> I delete some tag attributes for this explanation

*Here is a preview*: [image: Here is a preview]

> So I want to remove the white space on the right, I'm using pixel unit
>   in li elements, because I have not been able to make it works.

How can I dynamically change li elements width to fully fit on ul parent?

Answer (score 0):

All you're looking to do is make use of a percentage-based `width` on `.mail-attached-list>li`. The exact value that you need to use is dependent on the number of items that you want to display in a single row.

In addition to this, you can also make use of `text-align-last: center` on `.mail-attach-list`, which will center the collection of `<li>` elements:

```css
.mail-attach-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align-last: center; /* Center the elements */
}

.mail-attach-list>li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%; /* Dependant on the number of items per row */
}

.thumbnail {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
  background-color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mail-attach-list>li .mail-file-img,
.mail-attach-list>li .mail-file-icon {
  height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
}

.thumbnail .caption {
  padding: 9px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mail-attach-list list-ov">
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <div class="mail-file-icon">
        <i class="pli-file-excel"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="caption">
        <p class="text-primary mar-no text-overflow">Icon Example</p>
        <small class="text-muted text-overflow">
                    Added: <time data-toggle="timeago">4 days ago</time>
                </small>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <div class="mail-file-img">
        <img class="image-responsive" src="/uploads/2017/09/bg-img-7-400x300.jpg" alt="image">
      </div>
      <div class="caption">
        <p class="text-primary mar-no text-overflow">Image example</p>
        <small class="text-muted text-overflow">
                    Added: <time data-toggle="timeago">4 days ago</time>
                </small>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Yes, I know I should use percentage, but I don´t know how to calculate the number of elements when the windows size change and prevent too large elements.

Comment: You **could** use JavaScript to automatically calculate the number of elements, and adjust both the count and element's `width` while the screen is resizing, but I'd probably just recommend using multiple media queries. Find the width at which the items drop to a new line, and set a breakpoint there with a new `width`.

Comment: I probably prefer using media queries, but I have no idea how to calculate the inline number of elements, without changing the html structure in more divs

Comment: That's the beauty; you don't have to. You start at a full width, and then just manually shrink the window in F12 Developer Tools' responsive mode, and observe when the items drop to the next line. It will tell you the exact pixel width to set your media query breakpoint at. Then you just count up the number of elements on the line, and divide `100%` by that number to get your `width` (or just adjust the `width` value manually until it looks good). If there's 3 items at a width of `650px`, you set a query for the `650px` width with `33%` (`100%` / 3).

Comment: I understand, I will try it. Thanks for your help anyway